# What is the meaning of elevation in browser?

Tags: selenium, documentation, chromium

I used *OperaOptions* in my selenium test. As a argument i used *--allow-elevated-browser* but could not find the meaning. I searched a lot and even in documentation, there were no explanation.

I tried to find within these two url that belongs the chromium documentation.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc)

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

I am expecting to find good resources and to examine deeply.

Comment: Chromium doesn't have that switch: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc Where did you find that switch from?

Comment: I used for Opera and found while searching in here.

Comment: Chromium doesn't have that switch. Opera must have added that switch in their fork

Comment: Alright but chrome also using different version of this flag. So then what is elevation means in browsers??

Comment: Elevation means root or admin privilege.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense because when i did not add this setting, i was getting "DevToolsActivePort file" error.